# List all subclasses with fully qualified names

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to get a list of all subclasses of a given class with their fully qualified names. I wanted to copy it from Eclipse and paste into a text file like this:

```
 some.package.Class1
 some.package.Class2
 some.other.package.Class3
 ...
```

I've tried:

- doing `Search | Java | Type, Limit to implementors`. **But** this one for some strange reasons doesn't list subclasses of subclasses, only direct descendants.
- opening `Hierarchy` view for the class which prints all the subclasses in a tree component, **but** this view doesn't allow me to select all the rows and copy their names.

Any other tricks? There are hundreds of classes, so I wanted to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java

Comment: @Narayan: I've seen the question, but that one is about doing it programmatically. I hoped for a solution with a few clicks.

Comment: You could get a custom view indeed, lot less complicated the `TypeHierarchyViewPart` of the "hierarchy view", but using the same underlying mechanism to retrieve/display the hierarchy of classes.

Comment: If you can make Rich's solution work, I would propose his answer to be considered as the official one for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the pattern described in [http://internna.blogspot.com/2007/11/java-5-retrieving-all-classes-from.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20090411034350/http://internna.blogspot.com/2007/11/java-5-retrieving-all-classes-from.html) one can do it programmatically. It's a shame Eclipse can't do it OOTB. Doing it in Java code allows to do the filtering with no additional cost (e.g. `!(klazz.isEnum())`).

Answer (score 3):

The method in the Hierarchy view which does build the hierarchy tree is in the [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.typehierarchy.TypeHierarchyLifeCycle`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/typehierarchy/TypeHierarchyLifeCycle.java.htm):

```
private ITypeHierarchy createTypeHierarchy(IJavaElement element, IProgressMonitor pm) throws JavaModelException {
    if (element.getElementType() == IJavaElement.TYPE) {
        IType type= (IType) element;
        if (fIsSuperTypesOnly) {
            return type.newSupertypeHierarchy(pm);
        } else {
            return type.newTypeHierarchy(pm);
        }
    } else {
```

Which uses [org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/SourceType.java.htm#ixzz0RApcaF5s) class

```
/**
 * @see IType
 */
public ITypeHierarchy newTypeHierarchy(IJavaProject project, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws JavaModelException {
    return newTypeHierarchy(project, DefaultWorkingCopyOwner.PRIMARY, monitor);
}
```

So if you can get a [`IJavaElement`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaElement.java.htm), you can check those classes to emulate the same result.

It uses a [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CreateTypeHierarchyOperation`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/CreateTypeHierarchyOperation.java.htm#ixzz0RAqzCaBe)

Comment: So you suggest implementing a custom view in Eclipse.
Do I get it right?

Answer (score 3):

Update: my original answer wouldn't work as there is no context to the structured selection.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355818/renaming-packages-in-eclipse/1396717#1396717) shows how to contribute the action to the context menu and retrieve the structured selection. You can modify that type's execute method to process the Hierarchy (as VonC suggests, +1) and obtain all the sub-types and set the content to the clipboard as follows:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchPart activePart = HandlerUtil.getActivePart(event);
    try {
        IStructuredSelection selection = SelectionConverter
                .getStructuredSelection(activePart);

        IJavaElement[] elements = SelectionConverter.getElements(selection);

        if (elements != null && elements.length > 0) {
            if (elements[0] != null && elements[0] instanceof IType) {
                IType type = (IType)elements[0];

                ITypeHierarchy hierarchy =
                    type.newTypeHierarchy(new NullProgressMonitor());

                IType[] subTypes = hierarchy.getAllSubtypes(type);

                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                for (IType iType : subTypes) {
                    buf.append(iType.getFullyQualifiedName()).append("\n");
                }

                Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event);

                Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(shell.getDisplay());

                clipboard.setContents(
                    new Object[]{buf.toString()}, 
                    new Transfer[]{TextTransfer.getInstance()});
            }
        }
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        logException(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/java) can give you the complete list of classes which extend a given class or implement a specific interface. You will get it in the nWire navigator, which does not provide a copy command.

However, you can tap into the nWire database, which is a standard H2 database and has a very simple structure, and get everything you need with a simple query. We will be introducing reporting capabilities some time in the future.

IMHO, it will be less of an effort and you'll get a tool which gives you a lot more.

Comment: I've installed the plugin. How do I "tap into the nWire database". I don't see any view like this. Neither does the website help about it. Or should I use some database client to access it? What is the database name then?

Comment: Send me an email to support [at] nwiresoftware.com and I'll send you more details.