# Find related types that can be instantiated

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In Eclipse (Mars, FWIW), I'm trying to construct a list of types that are related to another type. By "related" I mean that I might at one time want the supertypes of type `X`, and at another time I might want the subtypes of type `X`. So far, so good. This sounds a lot like [Eclipse "Open Type" dialog restricted to a particular interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463114/eclipse-open-type-dialog-restricted-to-a-particular-interface). But...

I only want types that can actually be used at a particular point in code. Say, for example, that I wanted to replace the `null` in the below:

```
myFoo.setBar(null);
```

where `setBar()` is declared as follows:

```
public class Foo {
    // ...
    public void setBar(Bar theNewBar) {
        this.myBar = theNewBar;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I don't care about references to existing instances of `Bar` or its subtypes, I just care about `Bar` itself and subtypes thereof that I could instantiate on the spot, as if I were about to write:

```
myFoo.setBar(new SubBar());
```

So, specifically, types that are declared `private` would be excluded. `Local` types would be excluded (unless I can determine that they are declared within the method that I'm working with at the time. Anonymous inner classes declared elsewhere are out. And so is...wait for it...any type that is not visible based on access rules defined in its declaring plug-in (i.e. its plug-in doesn't `export` it). (This is Eclipse after all, and I care about conforming to the plug-in model.) There are Code Assist options that will exclude those types (CODEASSIST_DISCOURAGED_REFERENCE_CHECK and CODEASSIST_FORBIDDEN_REFERENCE_CHECK do what I want, I think) but Code Assist isn't able to discriminate by subtype or supertype.

So basically, if I can't instantiate it directly, and I can't write an anonymous inner class for it, I don't want to see it.

I've tried using `ITypeHierarchy`, but I can't see any methods either in creating it or in the `ITypes` that it returns that can be used to discriminate on the criteria that I've mentioned above.

`IType.isLocal()` and `IType.isAnonymous()` help. I can use them to rule out the local and anonymous types. But the others? For example, I don't care whether a type is `protected` or `package default`, I care whether I can instantiate it. Some `protected` or `package default` types can be instantiated at any given point in code, and others cannot.

I *do*, however, want to see types that could be instantiated if their declaring plug-in was added to my manifest.mf dependencies.

How can I go about either finding the types that I want (either using `ITypeHierarchy` or any other mechanism), or excluding the types that I don't want from `ITypeHierarchy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IType`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IType.html) is an [`IMember`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMember.html), which has the [`int getFlags()`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMember.html#getFlags--)
 method returning flags defined by [`Flags`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/Flags.html), which has good helper methods, e.g.:

```
Flags.isAbstract(iType.getFlags())
Flags.isInterface(iType.getFlags())
Flags.isPackageDefault(iType.getFlags()) // You then compare package yourself
Flags.isProtected(iType.getFlags()) // You then compare package yourself
Flags.isPublic(iType.getFlags())
```

Comment: Promising. Assuming I can do the correct package comparison, and I don't see why that wouldn't work, that solves a large chunk of the problem. Any insight into the part about excluding types that aren't exported by their plug-ins?