# How do I rename a package in a Gradle project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, package, rename

I have a Gradle project that contains packages that I'd like to rename from "com.bar.pkg1" to "com.foo.pkg1".   I would use Refactor -> Rename except the listing in Package Explorer looks like:

```
myproject
  com
    bar
      pkg1
```

so I can't select the entire "com.bar.pkg1" path to rename.   I tried to ask Package Explorer to change from hierarchical to flat view, but that had no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming packages in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355818/renaming-packages-in-eclipse)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the package presentation style to *flat* first:

[image]

Comment: TImothy, thanks for your answer, but (as I said in my question) I tried flattening the Package Presentation in Package Explorer but that had no effect.   I  think that somehow I need to convince Eclipse that this is a Java project, as well as a Gradle project.

Comment: Did you open the *Java* perspective and the *package explorer* within it? What is your eclipse version? Did you import the Project as *existing Gradle Project*?

Comment: Yes, I opened the Java perspective and Package Explorer within it.   Yes, I imported the project as an _existing gradle project_ (because I could not figure how to import it as a Java project, since the import-> only lists Java EE.)   I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Before digging deeper: can you switch to a more recent eclipse version?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'm using Eclipse Luna; recent enought?

Comment: *" I'm using Eclipse Luna; recent enought?"* not really, *Neon* is currently on R3...